# How to get tick marks right using useOuterStrips and doubleYScale (lattice) together?

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I want to make a plot like the minimal example below using useOuterStrips and doubleYScale from the latticeExtra package. It does work quiet well but there is one major issue, the *left tick marks are covered by the panel title* (0, 1).
How can I fix this one?

[image]

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)
mtcars$am = as.factor(mtcars$am)
mtcars$cyl = as.factor(mtcars$cyl)

foo = xyplot(mpg ~ hp|cyl*am, data=mtcars)
bar = xyplot(qsec ~ hp|cyl*am, data=mtcars)

FooBar = doubleYScale(foo, bar)
useOuterStrips(FooBar)
```